# Restoring VS 2017 to the its last stable state before cancelling an update?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I run the Visual Studio installer to update to version 15.4.0, but my internet connection was unstable that I had to cancel the installation. now I got this message when I open Visual Studio:

[image]

this is the message text:

> The setup for this installation of Visual Studio is not complete.
>   Please run the Visual Studio Installer again to correct the issue.

My question is: can I run VS again without having to update, with its latest-installed update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to fix the installation first. Either by re-running the installation or by removing the current installation and performing a fresh install.